# How do I generate a recursive query to get information from two tables

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a request to get all child records

```
with recursive cte (id, parentId) as 
(
    select id, parentId 
    from users 
    where id = 1 

    union all 

    select p.id, p.parentId 
    from users p 
    inner join cte on p.parentId = cte.id 
) 
select * from cte
```

there is also a user_info table

```
id, userId, login
```

I need to query here for more information. How can i do this?
I tried adding an extra inner join, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join that second table at the end:

```
with recursive cte (id, parentId) as (
    select     id,
               parentId
    from       users
    where      id = 1

    union all

    select     p.id,
               p.parentId 
    from       users p 
    inner join cte 
            on p.parentId = cte.id 
) 
select    * 
from      cte
left join user_info 
       on userId = cte.id
```